# помогите разобраться stringReader.Read()

Tags: c#, .net, потоки-данных

не могу понять, как реализовать этот метод.
**TODO. Implement the method by reading the next character with StringReader.Read method.**
Вот что у меня получилось

```
public static bool ReadNextCharacter(StringReader stringReader, out char currentChar)
    {            
        currentChar = (char)stringReader.Read();
        bool result = false;

        int c = stringReader.Read();

        if (c != -1)
        {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

а вот какие тесты ожидаются

```
    [TestCase(0, 'L', 'o', ExpectedResult = true)]
    [TestCase(1, 'o', 'r', ExpectedResult = true)]
    [TestCase(2, 'r', 'e', ExpectedResult = true)]
    [TestCase(3, 'e', 'm', ExpectedResult = true)]
    [TestCase(4, 'm', ' ', ExpectedResult = true)]
    [TestCase(124, 'U', 't', ExpectedResult = true)]
    [TestCase(444, '.', ' ', ExpectedResult = true)]
    [TestCase(448, ' ', ' ', ExpectedResult = false)]
```

как я понял задание: у меня есть строка, в ней я нахожу символ. Если его нет - возвращаю -1 и false соответственно. Но я не уверен, что правильно понял задание...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы перемудрили. Считывать символ надо 1 раз, а не 2.

```
public static bool ReadNextCharacter(StringReader stringReader, out char currentChar)
{            
    int code = stringReader.Read();
    if (code == -1)
    {
        currentChar = '\0';
        return false;
    }
        
    currentChar = (char)code;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А подскажите, я правильно понимаю, что .Read() - это своего рода forach в массиве, и перебирает каждый символ до конца строки?

Comment: @Peterblr нет, это не `foreach`.